# Strange xinit problem

Tags: ssh, xinit

I am using LFS-based custom Linux. When I try to start "xinit" then it fails to start with following error:

> Fatal server error:
>
> (EE) Cannot move old log file
> "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old"

But strangely, If I take SSH session of this machine then try to execute the same command then X start without any issue.

Both times, I executed this command by root only.

Comment: Any Display-manager? `ls -al /usr/binXorg` I hope this is the right path.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you don't close the X session peacefully.
Running

`rm /var/log/Xorg.X.log.old` is safe. You can also back up this log somewhere else.

**EDIT:** After you make a space for it, you should either move this log file "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old", or to remove it. 
These logs are usually saved by ascending the index number /var/log/Xorg.0.log, /var/log/Xorg.1.log, and they can't be overwritten.

`rm /var/log/Xorg.X.log`

Comment: I also tried this before posting the question. It says "Unable to create /var/log/Xorg.0.log file"